# Auto-Shrinking All Databases Files To Their Minimum Size In Sql Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, restore, disk-space

I restore my all databases in production to my development environment monthly. Development server has 4 TB disk space and there are 4 different instances over it which containt databases on the production server. In Development, i can truncate and shrink some big-sized tables to expand free disk space. The purpose of doing this process is the complaint of software developers about the development server slowness. I talked to system administrator team and they informed me that the slowness was because of the insufficient disk space area. So, i make this work. My question is about how i can shrink all database files to their minimum size after truncating related tables. So, should i make it with powershell, and how?

Comment: Insufficient disk should not be a significant factor for performance. You either have room to restore or you dont.  Fragmented indexes, poor statistics and/or insufficient RAM are more likely the culprits.

Comment: @SirSwears-a-lot But, i restore databases from my production and i rebuild my all indexes before taken every backup. Maybe RAM can cause that issue but system team strongly offers me to increase free disk space. I don't know :/

Comment: Rather than assuming thats the problem, you need to start a methodical process of elimination and performance tuning. If your developers complain of bad performance then start there. Find what performs badly then find out why. If you really want to shrink dbs then you could script it. But i think uts a red-herring and may do more harm than good.

Comment: Is there any script which does this work? @SirSwears-a-lot

Comment: Please, read Paul Randal's [Avoiding Knee-Jerk Performance Troubleshooting](https://sqlperformance.com/2014/02/sql-performance/knee-jerk-performance-troubleshooting) and [SQL Server Wait Statistics (or please tell me where it hurts…)](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/wait-statistics-or-please-tell-me-where-it-hurts/) articles.

Answer (score 1):

> My question is about how i can shrink all database files to their minimum size after truncating related tables

To answer your question directly, this is done using `DBCC SHRINKFILE` command -

```
DBCC SHRINKFILE (YourDatabaseLogicalFileName,<desired size in MB>)
```

Here you can read more information on how to use this commnand
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-shrinkfile-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

But, as other comments already mentioned, the reason of poor performance lies somewhere else and you need to start a methodical process of collecting and analyzing performance information (Performance Counters, Waits, Top heaviest queries, etc.)

Among other reasons, possible that poor performance in your Dev environment could be simply because system specification of Dev environment (CPU, RAM, Storage, Network etc.) is much weaker/worse than your Production; or Developers could be running some heavy and not tuned queries in Dev environment, that they do not run on Production